# Is it possible to set a parameter inside an otherwise constant String?

Tags: java, string

I am using a set of constant Strings for text anonymization. One of the strings should go something like "[Town in the state of XX]", where XX is to be replaced later with an actual state (the rest of the string remains as is).

My question is: is there a way to do this "elegantly" (in the spirit of a SQL [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html))?
Or should I just put XX and then do myString.replace("XX", "someState"), in which case, the string can no longer be a constant :(

EDIT: Just realized that String.replace returns a new String, so myString could still be a constant with this method.

Comment: Doing `string.replace` does nothing to `string`, but rather returns a new string. I am assuming that by prepared statement you mean that you have place holders in your string which are replaced by some actual value.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that too, as you can see from the edit :)
And yes, that is exactly what I mean: I have place holders to replace with a real value.

Comment: In that case I think that either fits (using `string.replace` or `string.format`).

Comment: The danger with this approach is if you do more that one replace. i.e. `str="First name ff last name ll"" str.replace("ff","Molly") -> "First name Molly last name ll" str.replace("ll","Smith") -> "First name MoSmith last name Smith"`

Comment: @Vixen, yes, this is exactly the kind of thing that made me want to avoid `String.replace`, even though I am not _currently_ doing more than one replacement. But I think `String.format` should do just fine. The Formatter class seems a bit of an overkill for my case, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `%s` instead of `XX`, then you can simply use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class

And conveniently from system out

```
System.out.format("My name is '%s' and i am %d years old. My party will be at '%s'.", name, years, time);
```